# How to retrieve a list of all users from a Power BI app using the Power BI Rest API?

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I'm looking for a way to gain insight who has access to what information product in the Power BI Service. How do I retrieve a list of users per Power BI App using the Power BI REST API?

[image: Publish App - Access - Permissions]

I've tried the Get Apps endpoint, which returns a list of all installed apps in our domain.

```bsh
Login-PowerBI 
$apps = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/apps" -Method Get 
$apps
```

And returns a list, for example:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "f089354e-8366-4e18-aea3-4cb4a3a50b48",
      "description": "The finance app",
      "name": "Finance",
      "publishedBy": "Bill",
      "lastUpdate": "2019-01-13T07:46:53.094+00:00"
    },
    {
      "id": "3d9b93c6-7b6d-4801-a491-1738910904fd",
      "description": "The marketing app",
      "name": "Marketing",
      "publishedBy": "Ben",
      "lastUpdate": "2018-11-13T07:46:53.094+00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, the list of users is not included here. Is it possible to retrieve a list of users some other way?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to get this using the API. Plus, it doesn't make much sense to support such lists, considering apps available for the entire organization.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

A Power BI app can indeed be published to an entire organization. However, most apps have restricted access to specified groups or individuals. In that case it would make sense.

Comment: There is an existing feature request on the Power BI UserVoice site https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/34923397-rest-api-apps-list-and-specific-app-contents-repo